# Принтер начинает печатать с задержками иногда до 20 мин

Tags: принтер, ubuntu

Установлена UBUNTU 10.04.3. Выполняет роли файл-сервера и принт-сервера в рабочей группе WindowsXP. Принтер HP LJ 1320 печатает с задержками иногда до 20 мин, а иногда сразу. Бвыает не хочет печатать вовсе. Пишет: плохое соединение. Перезагружаюсь в WindowsXP - печатает без проблем. Делаю вывод - с проводами всё в порядке. Возвращаюсь в UBUNTU  - печатает. Установлены samba, cups, hplip. В качестве файл-сервера работает без нареканий.

Comment: Избавьтесь от Windows. На Linux HP LJ работает без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Исправленный драйвер можно скачать по [этой ссылке](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/hp/hp-laserjet_1320).